# Is there an Equivalent to `Enumerable` for defining mathematical operations in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am creating a wrapper class for Ruby's NArray (numeric array).  I would like my class to respond to all of the standard mathematical operators (+, +=, -, -=, *, *=, etc) in the same way that an instance of NArray does.  I know how to make wrappers for `Array`s and other `Enumerable` objects, include `Enumerable` in the wrapper, and define an `each` method that just redirects to the wrapped `Enumerable` object.  I would like something similar with the NArray.  Is there a single module to include/method I can define that will define the whole bevy of mathematical operators to target the wrapped NArray?  Or do I have to define them all manually?

Comment: But how would such a generic module know how those methods(/operators) should be implemented for your class? In other words, what would be the one common method that they all call? `Enumerable` requires only `each`, what would your hypothetical module only require?

Comment: I think the right answer to your question is "Yes, you'll have to define the implementation of each operator manually"—for the reasons @AndrewMarshall just described.

Comment: Well, things like powers and roots can be inferred from existing mathematic operations, I guess. If the core operators are defined, lots of other things can be done. It would be an interesting project for mathematical/scientific projects to have a Math module or something of that nature.

Comment: If you've ever learnt a functional language, often the basic tutorials implement stuff like `*` and `/` using just `+` and `-` operators, to add and subtract 1, then recurse. Logically Math can be built up from some pretty basic building blocks.

Comment: They can be. And that's theoretically interesting, but who actually does that?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I understand that Enumerable works by supplying a bunch of methods that are defined in terms of the one core method `each`, and that there is no equivalent for math (in practice).  However this is just one way of implementing a forwarding system-- when you define `each` to just call the `each` of a wrapped `Array', the effect is forwarding all Enumerable methods to that `Array`.  This kind of forwarding is what I need, and need not be implemented the same way.  I recognize that my question implied that's what I was looking for though, so thank you everyone for clearing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Forwardable`:

```
require 'forwardable'
class MyWrapper

  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@narray, :+, :*, # etc...

  def initialize(narray)
    @narray = narray
  end
end
```

I'm not sure this will work with the `+=` et al methods (I don't know exactly how they are implemented, but I believe they are a feature of the parser and not actually methods you can reference).

Calling `+=` on an instance of MyWrapper would set the reference to the result of that operation, so you would need to figure out a way for that to return the same instance. That raises the question - is that what you want to do (return a wrapped NArray as the result of mathematical operations), or do you expect your NArray to handle the returns?

Comment: Actually, you'll find that `+=` and `-=` etc are not methods. The Ruby interpreter (loosely) translates them to `obj = obj + x` etc, so you don't need to worry about dealing with reassignment, provided you've defined the `+` or the `-`.

Comment: Right - I unintentionally said it the other way around. Fixed. But if the method is delegated to the object assigned to the instance variable, it will be reassigned to an object of that class, not the wrapper.

Comment: Awesome, this is the kind of thing I was looking for.  I had no idea this module existed.  It would be nice if I had the ability to return the same object (or another `MyWrapper` object) from these operations with only the underlying NArray changed.  Any ideas?  Basically I would need a kind of 'packager' method to catch the output of all the forwarded methods and rewrap it.